# Python find and replace unique key syntax from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got one HTML template, with someone pre-defined variables. I want to put values to the variables.

My template :

```
temp_string = """<td style="font-size:18px;">Dear {{var:name:"user"}}, welcome and congratulations on joining stack. Your age is {{var:age:"0"}}</td></tr>"""
```

My Dict :

```
my_data = {'name': 'Foo', 'age': 20}
```

Final Output

```
"""<td style="font-size:18px;">Dear Foo, welcome and congratulations on joining stack. Your age is 20</td></tr>"""
```

My code

```
>>> temp_string = """<td style="font-size:18px;">Dear {{var:name:"user"}}, welcome and congratulations on joining stack. Your age is {{var:age:"0"}}</td></tr>"""
>>> my_data = {'name': 'Foo', 'age': 20}
>>> for key,value in my_data.items():
...     if key in temp_string:
...             temp_string.replace(key, value)
```

Comment: Formulate a regular expression for your placeholders, then look into the [function-accepting form of `re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: @AKX here I need to process this whole **{{var:name:"user"}}**

Comment: Sure thing. `{{(.+?)}}` is a regular expression that would capture that placeholder.

Comment: The last bit is the default value?

Comment: @tobias_k yes the last bit default one

Comment: Then iterating the dict items won't really work, since a default implies that one of the placeholders might not be _in_ the dict.

Comment: @tobias_k ya, so what is the best approach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go...

- As mentioned in comments, `re.sub()` has a form that accepts a function that will return the replacement value given a match object.

  - We check whether the contents of the placeholder (capture group 1) begins with `var:`, then split it into exactly three parts (split with max 2 splits).
  - If the placeholder doesn't start with `var:`, it is passed through verbatim. You might want to raise an error instead.
- Since the default values seem to be quoted, we use `ast.literal_eval()` to unquote them.

```
import re
import ast


def replace_placeholders(template, data):
    def replacer(match):
        content = match.group(1)
        if content.startswith("var:"):
            _, name, quoted_default = content.split(":", 2)
            if name in data:
                return str(data[name])
            return str(ast.literal_eval(quoted_default))
        # Pass other content through as-is
        return match.group(0)

    return re.sub(r"{{(.+?)}}", replacer, template)


print(
    replace_placeholders(
        template="""Dear {{var:name:"user"}}, welcome and congratulations on joining stack. Your age is {{var:age:"0"}}""",
        data={"name": "Foo", "age": 20},
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is to use a regex with named capture groups that is specific to your template format; this can simplify the replacement function:

```py
import re

def replacevars(m):
    return str(my_data.get(m.group('var'), m.group('default')))
    
temp_string = """<td style="font-size:18px;">Dear {{var:name:"user"}}, welcome and congratulations on joining stack. Your age is {{var:age:"0"}}</td></tr>"""
my_data = { 'name': 'Foo', 'age': 20 }

result = re.sub(r'\{\{var:(?P<var>\w+):"(?P<default>[^"]+)"\}\}', replacevars, temp_string)
print(result)

# demonstrate with default value
my_data = { 'age' : 10 }

result = re.sub(r'\{\{var:(?P<var>\w+):"(?P<default>[^"]+)"\}\}', replacevars, temp_string)
print(result)
```

Output:

```html
<td style="font-size:18px;">Dear Foo, welcome and congratulations on joining stack. Your age is 20</td></tr>
<td style="font-size:18px;">Dear user, welcome and congratulations on joining stack. Your age is 10</td></tr>
```